# Python UDP Socket server

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I implemented an UDP socket server using python.The source code of the program shows below.

```
import socket
port_number = 116 #Checked it with various numbers
addressBar = list();
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)   
server_socket.bind(('localhost', port_number))              
print "UDPServer Waiting for client on port ",port_number
while True:
    dataFromClient, address = server_socket.recvfrom(256)
    if(address not in addressBar):
                addressBar.append(address)
    print dataFromClient
    if(len(addressBar)>1):
                for add in addressBar:
                        if(address != add ):
                                server_socket.sendto(dataFromClient, add)
    else:
        server_socket.sendto("No any connected devices", address)
    print addressBar
```

This server is working fine. But now I need to this, be an on-line server. I tried to host this in openShift (https://openshift.redhat.com/app/login?then=%2Fapp%2Fconsole%2Fapplications). but it was unsuccessful. I have 0 experience with python web application development so I need your kind help to get an idea bout "How to host this server and where to host ?"

Following source code shows the client side of the application.

```
import socket
print "Client"
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)    #This creates socket

while 1:
    data=raw_input("Message:")
    client_socket.sendto(data, ('localhost',117))
    print "Sending request"
    recv_data, addr = client_socket.recvfrom(256)
    print "Message<<Clent2>>",recv_data
client_socket.close()
```

Comment: the first obvious thing, you need to check if UDP port that you use is opened on the hosting server. Most likely it's firewalled.

Comment: Opps thanks for the advice ill do it ... but when I trying to start the server it says "No module call socket". So I think this cannot be the problem. Open shift is supporting both python 2.7 and 3.0 here I used 2.7. Since "socket" is inbuilt module in python this cannot be happen.

Comment: Then it's a qs to their support about version that they use and why they don't have socket module, which should be in a standard lib in 2.7: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py - that's what I have on Linux.

Comment: Some times it may be a problem in the program. but some how it is not working is there any free host for python that I can try with

Comment: Try AWS' free tier - http://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=AWS_Free_Tier_2013_C&sc_country=US&sc_publisher=Google&sc_medium=b_core_cloud_computing_e-aws_free&sc_content=40951085802&sc_detail=Aws%20free%20tier&sc_category=aws_cloud_computing&sc_segment=cloud_computing&sc_matchtype=e

Answer (score 3):

```
server_socket.bind(('localhost', port_number))
```

This is your problem - you need to bind to all interfaces, otherwise only connections from the same machine will be successful. Do this:

```
# bind to all interfaces
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', port_number))
```